# JavaScript returns false values

Tags: javascript, validation, onsubmit

I wrote 3 functions for my website, these look like this:

```
function val_mail(mail)
{
    if(!isNaN(mail))
    {
        alert("Ungültige E-Mail!");
        return false;   
    }
    if(mail.indexOf('.')===-1 || mail.indexOf('@')===-1)
    {
        alert("Ihre Email enthält keinen Punkt, oder @ Zeichen");
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

function check_numeric(form_value)
{
    if(form_value.indexOf("€")!==-1)
    {
        alert("Bitte keine €-Zeichen anfügen, geben Sie bitte nur Numerische werte an");
        return false;
    }
        
    if(isNaN(form_value))
    {
        alert("Wert ist nicht numerisch!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
}

function val_steuernummer(steuernummer)
{
    if(isNaN(steuernummer))
    {
        return false;   
    }
    if(steuernummer/100000000 < 1)
    {
        return false;   
    }
    if(steuernummer/100000000 > 10)
    {
        return false;   
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I test these Functions in a JavaScript console everything works, but if I want to combine these Functions to one which checks all 3 values it doesn't work. Although I'm not sure if this code is valid: `onSubmit="return check_all()"`

Can you please show me how I write a function which checks everything?

********News**********
With this code:

```
function check_all(mail,steuernummer,kinder)
{
    return val_mail(mail) &&val_steuernummer(steuernummer) && check_numeric(kinder);
}
```

And this command int the JavaScript console

```
check_all('hey@me.de','123456789','7')
```

it returns true, but when I want to use it in an html file it doesn't work?

Is this Initialization correct:

```
var steuernummer = $("#steuernummer");
var kinder = $("#kidner_anzahl");
var mail = $("#mail");
NOTE: These are global variables
```

And is this onSubmit correct?

```
<form name="fragebogen" action="next.php" method="post" onSubmit="return check_all()" id="formular">
```

Comment: Can't really help you without seeing `check_all`

Comment: and `check_all()` looks like?

Comment: Well, thats the point I tried everything for check_all() but nothing works, so I asked the community

Comment: `!isNaN(mail)` looks a bit weird…

Comment: you can also try HTML5 form validations http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
function check_all() {

  /* get values to pass to functions */
  var mail = ...
  var form_value = ...
  var steuernummer = ...

  return val_mail(mail) &&
         val_steuernummer(steuernummer) && 
         check_numeric(form_value);
}
```

#### Edit

Nothing to do with the onsubmit attribute, everything to do with how you are calling *check_all*

> Is this Initialazon correct:
>
> var steuernummer = $("#steuernummer");
>   var kinder = $("#kidner_anzahl");
>   var mail = $("#mail"); NOTE: These are global
>   variables

No. At a guess, you are passing jQuery (though other libraries use *$* and selectors) and are passing jQuery objects to the functions, not the value of the related controls. Presumably you want the values of the controls when called, so pass them:

```
function check_all() {
  return val_mail(mail.val()) &&
         val_steuernummer(steuernummer.val()) && 
         check_numeric(kinder.val());
}
```

The simplest way to implement this is to pass a reference to the form in the submit listener:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return check_all(this)">
```

Then in the function:

```
function check_all(form) {
  return val_mail(form.mail.value) &&
         val_steuernummer(form.steuernummer.value) && 
         check_numeric(form.kidner_anzahl.value);
}
```

It helps greatly if you post a "working" example that you've reduced to the minimum that shows your issue. Then others aren't trying to guess what they can't see.

Comment: No, this also doesn't work may it has something to to with the onSubmit attribute?